# Gamepad keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, gamepad

Assuming I know the "name" of the key of my gamepad, HOW:

How can I open Emulation Station by pressing that key in my gamepad, normally I type `emulationstation` in terminal and works of corse...

But I want with my gamepad...
And if possible only when Emulation Station is closed/down/off...

I already tried add that on System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom shortcuts; but don't let me input the shortcut with my gamepad key/button, only with "normal" keyboard keys

Any help will be appreciated

PS: I guess it will be with a script or with issue a command in terminal?

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for the same thing! Maybe you can try AutoHotKey, though you might have to learn it a bit before using it. 
[Remapping a Joystick](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/RemapJoystick.htm)

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...